# Organizing a huge .css file with Visual Studio extension?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

This is my css file:

[image]

Guys is there any extension in the visual studio that will help me organize my .css file?

Obviously i am a beginner in the .css / html languages.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can just right-click > format document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a minified CSS so you need a tool that is able to "un-minify" it.
As far as I know VS Code by default doesn't have a formatter for CSS that can do it, but for my minified CSS this one does the trick:

[CSS Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aeschli.vscode-css-formatter)

After installation, you can right click -> Format Document inside your CSS file.

As for "organizing a huge file" - I mean organizing it into smaller modules, you could use a preprocessor like [SASS](https://sass-lang.com/) (or a bundler like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) for more "complicated" applications).